# Changing my site theme often

Tags: website-design, themes, templates

I'm planning on selling website templates.  My first thoughts were the development of my actual site.  After thinking about it for a while, what if, instead of my site having one common theme, what if the page changed themes ever so often to those of my products.  There would be a link saying what theme it was and it would bring them to a page to buy/demo it.

My question it, would this make it to complicated for my client?  If the client saw an unrecognized theme on the page, would he/she leave?  Would the difference in colors and menus (assuming that the layout it nearly the same, just different styles and animations, etc.) be too much for my clients?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your better bet is to have different featured products, not changing the site. You need to identify a difference between the site and the features. The site is what will give users confidence ( in the brand name and everything that goes with it ), so you need to keep that brand confidence, which giving variation that suggests a range of products and keeping their fingers on the button.

So keep themes the same, but change content.

Comment: +1, I agree that users are more accustomed to, and even have come to expect, a "featured product" area that changes frequently.

Comment: I really do like the idea for the 'featured product' area.  I guess that-that is a suitable replacement for my idea :)

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, frequent redesigns are a big no-no. Not only do they re-position all the UI elements, but your visitors may also think it's a different website from the one they wanted to visit. This is especially important in case of e-commerce websites and other services where money is involved.

This is true even if you don't drastically change the layout. Internet users make very fast decisions and a colour change can be enough for them to go back where they came from.

Answer (score 2):

It is a principle of branding that you should create something consistently recognizable. You want to be memorable and easy to understand, and having a consistent design is part of that. Every design has a learning curve, and once people learn where everything is on your site, they don't want to be challenged repeatedly to learn it again.